# How to get the median values of correlation coefficients for transcripts from the same gene family

Tags: shell-script

I want to get the median values of correlation coefficients for transcripts from the same gene family.

Input_file:

```
Trancript_id    Correaltion coefficient R   Gene_name   Transcript_name
ENST00000588750 0.29000968  APOC1   APOC1-202
ENST00000592535 0.066122367 APOC1   APOC1-208
ENST00000592885 0.021134868 APOC1   APOC1-209
ENST00000589078 -0.026632376    APOC1   APOC1-204
ENST00000507983 0.027572878 APOC1P1 APOC1P1-201
ENST00000575148 0.022259741 APOC1P1 APOC1P1-204
ENST00000574565 0.162023776 APOC1P1 APOC1P1-203
ENST00000590360 -0.040690609    APOC2   APOC2-203
ENST00000585786 0.120824189 APOC2   APOC2-202
ENST00000343267 -0.022932868    APOD    APOD-201
ENST00000458447 -0.013565352    APOD    APOD-204
ENST00000463719 0.114022335 APOD    APOD-205
ENST00000252486 0.006889061 APOE    APOE-201
ENST00000446996 0.005700132 APOE    APOE-204
ENST00000434152 0.220318481 APOE    APOE-203
```

Outputfile:

```
Trancript_id    Gene_name   r   median r
ENST00000588750 APOC1   0.29000968  0.043628618
ENST00000592535 APOC1   0.066122367 
ENST00000592885 APOC1   0.021134868 
ENST00000589078 APOC1   -0.026632376    
ENST00000507983 APOC1P1 0.027572878 0.027572878
ENST00000575148 APOC1P1 0.022259741 
ENST00000574565 APOC1P1 0.162023776 
ENST00000590360 APOC2   -0.040690609    0.04006679
ENST00000585786 APOC2   0.120824189 
ENST00000343267 APOD    -0.022932868    -0.013565352
ENST00000458447 APOD    -0.013565352    
ENST00000463719 APOD    0.114022335 
ENST00000252486 APOE    0.006889061 0.006889061
ENST00000446996 APOE    0.005700132 
ENST00000434152 APOE    0.220318481
```

Comment: OK. What code/script have you tried and how does it do?

Comment: Apologies, but I have not tried any script. I did this in excel for one file. But as I have such 86000 files so have to use a script. I have calculated median in past with commnand line but that was for calculating a single median value from 1 file. However, in this file median needs to be calculated on the basis of gene names in the 2nd column and honestly, I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: I would suggest adding that info (that the input files are excel files, and the output file should be an excel file) to the question.

Comment: Do you specifically need the median value to be appended to the *first* line (and only the first line) of each `Gene_name`?

Comment: The input file is not a excel file and I don't want output file in excel format. I just calculated the median values in excel (because I don't know how to do it in the command line for an input file like this)

Comment: @ steeldriver No

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [GNU datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/) to calculate the grouped medians. Assuming the columns are general whitespace delimited (if they are tab delimited, you may omit the `--whitespace` option; for CSV format use `-t,`):

```
$ datamash --whitespace --headers groupby 3 median 2 < Input_file 
GroupBy(coefficient)    median(Correaltion)
APOC1   0.0436286175
APOC1P1 0.027572878
APOC2   0.04006679
APOD    -0.013565352
APOE    0.006889061
```

Since your data are sorted on the `Gene_name`, you can then `join` the results back to the input columns:

```
$ datamash --headers --whitespace groupby 3 median 2 < Input_file | 
    join --header -o1.1,0,1.2,2.2 -13 -21 Input_file -
Trancript_id coefficient Correaltion median(Correaltion)
ENST00000588750 APOC1 0.29000968 0.0436286175
ENST00000592535 APOC1 0.066122367 0.0436286175
ENST00000592885 APOC1 0.021134868 0.0436286175
ENST00000589078 APOC1 -0.026632376 0.0436286175
ENST00000507983 APOC1P1 0.027572878 0.027572878
ENST00000575148 APOC1P1 0.022259741 0.027572878
ENST00000574565 APOC1P1 0.162023776 0.027572878
ENST00000590360 APOC2 -0.040690609 0.04006679
ENST00000585786 APOC2 0.120824189 0.04006679
ENST00000343267 APOD -0.022932868 -0.013565352
ENST00000458447 APOD -0.013565352 -0.013565352
ENST00000463719 APOD 0.114022335 -0.013565352
ENST00000252486 APOE 0.006889061 0.006889061
ENST00000446996 APOE 0.005700132 0.006889061
ENST00000434152 APOE 0.220318481 0.006889061
```

If you do need the median values to be appended to only the first row of each group, you can pipe the whole thing through `awk 'seen[$2]++ {NF--} 1'`.

Comment: Can you please clarify the code written after `join`